# iOS Local Push notification not waking up device

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I'am developing a location aware iOS app that sends out local notification when near an iBeacon. I've setup the geofence to trigger when the device is approximately 5 meters away from the beacon.

Receiving the notification works fine, but i will only get the notification when i unlock the device (touch id or passcode) or power it on with the sleep wake button (shows the clock).

Is there anything i can do that the notification wakes up the device so the display lights up / vibrates / plays a sound like for example an iMessage does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iBeacons, you actually don't need to use geofences. What you want to do is use monitoring through Core Location like so:

```
CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:uuid.UUIDString];
                [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
                beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
                beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
                beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
```

Once you are monitoring for a beacon region, the app will automatically enter and exit when you encounter that signal through these core location methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

Inside these methods is where you want to show your local notification.

Please note that for iOS version 7.0 and newer you need to enter NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription into your info.plist in order to get location services working with iBeacons.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app registers for notification settings, requesting both Alert and Sound types.  As of iOS 8, unless the user grants this permission request, your notifications will not play sounds or wake up the phone.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) for more info.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
  UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationType) (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                           UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);

  UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];      
}
```